# How do I write <variableExpression> in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am writing the `<variableExpression>` as

```
<variableExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.String((not ibase.webitm.reports.utility.BaseReportMethods.isNull( $F{LOT_SL} )?(($F{QTY_PASSED}).doubleValue() > 0 && ($F{QTY_REJECTED}).doubleValue() > 0? $F{LOC_CODE} :(($F{QTY_PASSED}).doubleValue() > 0? $F{LOC_CODE} : (($F{QTY_REJECTED}).doubleValue() > 0? $F{LOC_CODE} :""))):""))]]></variableExpression>
```

where BaseReportMethods is my java clss and isNull() is method that return true or false according to condition.
But,
when I compile the report it gives me error as
Syntax error,insert "AssignmentOperator ArrayInitializer" to complete ArrayInitializerAssignement 
why it is can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

It could be 'not' in your expression. Try replacing with the normal not operator '!'.

From this:

new java.lang.String((**not** ibase.webitm.reports.utility.BaseReportMethods.isNull...

To this:

new java.lang.String((**!** ibase.webitm.reports.utility.BaseReportMethods.isNull...